# Explain regular expression for removing html code from String

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a regular expression which removes html code from a String :

```
var html = "<p>Dear sms,</p><p>This is a test notification for push message from center II.</p>";

text = html.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "")

alert(text)
```

This is the expression working on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/VgHr3/53/

The regular expression itself is `/(<([^>]+)>)/ig` . I don't fully understand how this expression works. Can provide an explanation ? I can find what each character by itself behaves by reading a cheatsheet  :http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

But what is the significance of "/ig" ?

Comment: `i` is case-insensitive and `g` is global. [Relevant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: @canon now sit back and watch the answers come flooding in!

Comment: At the risk of sounding redundant, global means it replaces all instances that are found, rather than just the first which is the default behavior.

Comment: Check it out on [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/gH3iF3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are global flags. Your cheat sheet actually lists them on the right side:

```
Regular Expressions Pattern Modifiers
g   Global match
i   Case-i­nse­nsitive
m   Multiple lines
s   Treat string as single line
x   Allow comments and white space in pattern
e   Evaluate replac­ement
U   Ungreedy pattern
```

Note that not all of these flags are supported by the JavaScript regular expression engine. For an authoritative list, see this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

So the "g" flag makes it global, so it replaces this pattern wherever it is found, instead of just the first instance (which is the default behavior of the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method).

The "i" flag makes it case-insensitive, so a pattern like `[a-z]+` will match `"foo"` and `"FOO"`. However, because your pattern only involves `<` and `>` characters, this flag is useless.